# What is the best way to limit the number of responses in each Sheets tab and account for user "preferences" through Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am trying to write some apps script that will sort a list of people into different activities based on what their preferences are.

For example, let's say the activities are swimming, painting, and video games. I have each of these activities as their own separate tab in Sheets. In the Google Form, I have a checkbox grid they can use to check off which activities they want as their first, second, or third preference.

John picks video games as his first preference, swimming second, and painting as his last preference. The script should first look at John's first preference and attempt to place him under the "video games" sheet tab. If this activity is "full" (I was thinking of limiting the number of rows in each activity sheet...will this work?), it will attempt to increment to the next preference (swimming) and attempt to place him under that tab instead.

I tried to look for similar solutions but couldn't find anything. Originally tried to create an array, add the person's activities in order of their preferences to said array, and then increment to the next activity if the sheet was full but it didn't pan out as how I hoped. Would love any ideas on how I can make this happen!

Comment: Welcome. Defining "full" in terms of the number of rows on a sheet should work and it is has the added advantage of being very easy to calculate. What row-count value  = "full", and does the same value apply to all three activities? Would you please post your script (even though it didn't pan out) and explain where you are having a problem. Did you install your script as an `onFormSubmit` trigger? Would you also share a copy of your spreadsheet ( excluding any private or confidential information), and include an example of a successful outcome.

Comment: Thanks!

Unfortunately what I'm working on is difficult to share without completely changing everything about the sheet to prevent self-identifying information. Let's say each activity only allows for 10 participants (so the activity sheets will have 10 participant rows). If there are already 10 sign-ups for video games, and John tries to also sign up for video games for his first preferences, the script should see that the video games sheet is full (over 10) and place him under the swimming tab instead which has only 6 people. This script will be ran only once so no triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information about how your data is set up or some code you may have tried is very difficult to give you a complete answer.

---

#### Option 1: Check in Javascript if the preference is maxed

You said in the comments that you only execute this script once, If that'the case you could just create a "dictionary" (take a look at [Associative Arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)) and store there all the information for later insert.

```
var dictionary = {};
dictionary["swimming"] = [];
dictionary["videoGames"] = [];
dictionary["painting"] = [];
```

After that you could just check for each preference if the array is full:

```
// After checking the preference exists
if dictionary[preference].length > 10: // 10 participants max
    Logger.log("This preference is full");
else:
    dictionary[preference].push(variable); // Whatever you want to insert here
```

And after that of course just go an insert all the variables in the corresponding sheets.

---

#### Option 2: Insert directly to the sheets and check if full

Another option could be to insert in the sheets directly checking if the sheet is already maxed out.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(preference);

if sheet.getLastRow() > 10:
    Logger.log("This preference is full");
else: 
    sheet.appendRow(["1st column", "2nd column", "3rd column"]);
```

In case you want to look a the reference for these functions.

- [`getLastRow()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)
- [`appendRow()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents)
- [`getSheetByName()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)